# Angular compiler and tsconfig.json

Tags: angular, typescript

I am running a simple Angular-CLI project. By adding `"compile": "ngc"` to my `package.json` , I can run

```
npm run compile
```

which invokes Angular compiler and creates some new files to my project like `home.component.ngfactory.js`. What I cannot understand is why **ngc** is using `tsconfig.json` (configuration for Typescript compiler) as to output its results. ***Is there any connection between Angular compiler and Typescript compiler?***

Comment: you can read the docs ...https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration

Comment: because it has to compile the typescript into javascript so it needs an output directory

Comment: Yes, Angular is written in TS so needs TSC to... C the TS. You generally don't see those files because `ng serve` and `ng build` largely operate in memory.

Answer (score 2):

please refer to [docs](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration) ...

> TypeScript is a primary language for Angular application development.
>   It is a superset of JavaScript with design-time support for type
>   safety and tooling.
>
> Browsers can't execute TypeScript directly. Typescript must be
>   "transpiled" into JavaScript using the tsc compiler, which requires
>   some configuration.
>
> This page covers some aspects of TypeScript configuration and the
>   TypeScript environment that are important to Angular developers,
>   including details about the following files:
>   [tsconfig.json](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#tsconfig)—TypeScript compiler configuration.
>  [typings](https://angular.io/guide/typescript-configuration#typings)—TypesScript
>   declaration files.
>
> **tsconfig.json**
>  Typically, you add a TypeScript configuration file called tsconfig.json to your project to guide the
>   compiler as it generates JavaScript files.
>
> **TypeScript Typings**
>
> Many JavaScript libraries, such as jQuery, the Jasmine testing
>   library, and Angular, extend the JavaScript environment with features
>   and syntax that the TypeScript compiler doesn't recognize natively.
>   When the compiler doesn't recognize something, it throws an error.
>
> Use TypeScript type definition files—d.ts files—to tell the compiler
>   about the libraries you load.

Comment: it uses it because ts files have to be compiled into js files

Comment: that was in reply to @Unknowndeveloper 's response

Comment: Sorry guys. I think Angular compiler has nothing to do with Typescript!! It compiles just HTML to JS. Isn't it? The Typescript compilation is done by the TS compiler.